# webelement list becomes NULL on frame switch

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Using `Python` & `Selenium web-diver`, I am generating reports from an HTML page.

```
#report name starts with 'std'
folderSize = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'std')]"))
reportList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'std')]")

innerIterator = 0
while ( innerIterator < folderSize) :

    reportList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'std')]")
    reportName = reportList[innerIterator].text

    ##### generate report    
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(reportName).click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)    

    driver.switch_to_default_content()
    driver.implicitly_wait(3) 
    reportList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'std')]")

    ##### reportList Becomes NULL here when invoked second time. First Report is successfully generated.
    ##### Unable to get seocnnd element in the list

    print("Generate report")

    innerIterator = innerIterator + 1
```

`reportList` becomes `NULL` after the call to `switch_to_default_content()` and subsequent calls to `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'std')]")` returns `NULL`